# Versionamento de código fonte com aprovação

Tags: versionamento, svn

Olá, hoje para versionamento de código na empresa utilizamos o Tortoise SVN e gostaríamos de começar a utilizar um versionador que quando o desenvolvedor commitasse alguma coisa antes das alterações serem mergeadas com o código do repositório passasse por uma aprovação antes, um gestor aprovasse o commit ou alteração e ai sim essas alterações iriam para o repositório.

Vocês poderiam me indicar alguma ferramenta que trabalhar dessa forma, será que o Git faz isso?

Obrigado.

Comment: Dá para usar qualquer coisa para fazer isto, o Git pode facilitar um pouco.

Comment: O Git com o Gerrit funciona perfeitamente para a sua necessidade.

Comment: O que vc quer é uma ferramenta de Code Review. Da uma olhada nessa lista: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_code_review

Answer (score 1):

[O SVN já faz isso](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html), mas como a própria documentação diz, é realmente necessário este tipo de configuração?

Falo isto porque alterações erradas podem ser facilmente revertidas. O problema é mais fácil de se resolver através de uma boa organização de projeto do que restringindo acessos.

Por exemplo, os usuários poderiam ser separados em grupos que só podem fazer *commits* em *branches*, e não no *trunk*. Isto deixaria o *merge* a cargo de um programador mais experiente.

Outra forma é [configurar restrições de acesso nos *hooks* de *pre-commit*](https://ist.berkeley.edu/as-ag/tools/usage/svn-govern-commit-permission.html).